# FreeMarker template loader returns 302 Found

Tags: java, freemarker

FreeMarker returns the following content of the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://someOtherUrl">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

It can not happen at all. How does FreeMaker gets it?
FreeMarker configuration is created and used:

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_22);
    ...
    @PostConstruct
    void init()
    {
        configuration.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
        configuration.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        configuration.setTemplateLoader(new TemplateLoader());
        configuration.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
...
   Template temp = configuration.getTemplate(sourceTemplateUrl);
```

Can I get rid of such "smart" behaviour?

**EDIT:**

```
public class TemplateLoader extends URLTemplateLoader
{
    private static final String LOCAL_PREFIX = "_" + Locale.ENGLISH;

    @Override
    protected URL getURL(final String url)
    {
        try
        {
            //get rid of "_en" in the url, FreeMarker set it based on Locale
            return new URL(url.replace(LOCAL_PREFIX, ""));
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AleksandrM, I've posted the code into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page isn't generated by FreeMarker. FreeMarker does no HTTP magic, it just generates text. (Of course, if you cause FreeMarker to load the template from an URL that returns this text, then it technically comes from FreeMarker.)

Also, your `TemplateLoader` <strike>doesn't look functional to me, as you just create URL-s from relative paths</strike> (update: you are passing in full URL-s, so it can work, but you will have to handle HTTP response codes too). But you aren't supposed to do such name changes there anyway. If you don't want localized lookup, just turn it off:

```
configuration.setLocalizedLookup(false);
```

Or if you need something trickier, check out `configuration.setTemplateLookupStrategy`.

Comment: thank you. What should be done in TemplateLoader. Client just sends url and FreeMarker loads template locates at this URLs. What else should I do in this class? Is there a way to get a response code in FreeMarker confguration, after invokation of configuration.getTemplate(someUrl);
?

Comment: I have just realized that you pass full URL-s to `getTemplate`. Unusual (and think through security implications), but then it should work. FreeMarker itself won't deal with HTTP response codes (or anything that's HTTP-specific). You have to program that knowledge into your `TemplateLoader` (see JavaDocs and other documentation), as it's specific to the storage mechanism. Like, if the URL returns HTTP 404, `findTemplateSource` should return `null`.